# Magento 2 Algolia Search Sort by Lowest Price etc show broken results

Tags: magento2, algolia

I have a Magento 2 project where algolia search is implemented. The search works fine but when we try to sort the results by anything other than relevance then the results are broken. 
[image]

I have setup a local deployment with a new algolia account and the sorting works fine. I inspected the response from algolia and found following:

On Live Site where the sorting does not work the response on sort actions is :
[image]

On local site where the sorting is working the response is:
[image]

There is a difference in the structure of response. Response on live site has an objectId node inside hits... Not sure if this can be the issue or is there something else that is wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: sure. I found the solution. it was configuration issue, initially I thought its a bug in Algolia extension so I posted here.

Comment: Even if it were a bug in Algolia it's still not a programming-related question.